# pgLoader connects but then hangs when connected to pgPool and not directly

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, pgloader

So I am implementing HA on PostgreSQL 11.  I have 2 VMs, and I am using pgPool to manage it.  So far so good.  Now, on the original DB1 VM I also had a few CSV files getting loaded using pgLoader.  If I point pgLoader directly to the DB1 or 2 box it works, but if I try and connect through pgPool, then I get a connection but then the pgLoader job hangs.  Not really getting any log output to speak of either.  We're trying postgre 11.5, pgPool II and the current version of pgLoader.

Anybody seen this before?  Thanks in advance.